# Collision Between SKSpriteNode and SKShapeNode

Tags: collision-detection, projectile-physics, swift

I'm trying to create a collision between two objects. One is a `SKSpriteNode` and the other is a `SKShapeNode`. The code I have so far for determining contact is:

```
 func didBeginContact( contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let firstBody  : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
        let SecondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

        if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Orange) && (SecondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Red)) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Red) && (SecondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Orange) {

            CollisionWithRed(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Red: SecondBody.node as! SKShapeNode)
        }


    }

    func CollisionWithRed (Orange: SKSpriteNode, Red:SKShapeNode){
       Orange.removeAllChildren()
       Red.removeAllChildren()
    }
```

The problem is that after the collision, the Orange and Red are not removed from the screen. They are still there.

The code for Orange is :

```
 func SpawnOranges () {
        let Orange = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Orange.png")
        Orange.size = CGSize (width: 80, height: 80)
        let MinValue = self.size.width / 8
        let MaxValue = self.size.width - 20
        Orange.zPosition = 7
        let SpawnPoint = UInt32 (MaxValue - MinValue)
        Orange.position = CGPoint (x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)), y: self.size.height)
        Orange.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:Orange.size)
        Orange.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Orange
        Orange.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Orange.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        Orange.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.red
        let action = SKAction.moveToY(-150, duration: 2.0)
        let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        Orange.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))

        addChild(Orange)
```

The code for Red is :

```
class Red: SKShapeNode{
    convenience init(path: UIBezierPath, color: UIColor, borderColor:UIColor) {
        self.init()
        self.path = path.CGPath
        self.fillColor = color
        self.strokeColor = borderColor



        Red = Red(path: projectilePath, color: UIColor.redColor(), 
          borderColor: UIColor.blackColor())
        Red.position = Settings.Metrics.projectileRestPosition
        Red.zPosition = 7
        Red.name = "Square"
        Red.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
        Red.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Orange
        Red.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Red.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Orange
        Red.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Orange
        Red.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        Red.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        addChild(Red)
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: What about if the SKShapeNode is part of an array? Can you get collision detection between the SKSpriteNode and array of SKShapenodes?

Answer (score 1):

You are removing their children which they don't have and to remove them you have to remove them from Parent. You can find more about children and parent [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/)

```
func CollisionWithRed (Orange: SKSpriteNode, Red:SKShapeNode){
       Orange.removeFromParent()
       Red.removeFromParent()
    }
```